# Toolbar background is by default white even if background is not set to white

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm using a toolbar in my activity where i'm not setting any type of white color as background but still even i'm not setting any background it's still white and what i want is that the white color should be removed from the toolbar and it should load the background which i'm trying to set please take a look at my code:

background_toolbar.xml:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="#66000000"/>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Table List"
            android:textColor="#679643"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.555" />

              <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mfilter"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.975"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.652" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0059ff</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Screenshot of activity:

[image]

Comment: where you apply your theme and background on toolbar ?

Comment: The toolbar usually assigns the apps primary color as a background color for it , your theme's primary color is #00000000 , you gave an opacity of 0% so maybe that's why its appearing the way it is. Try changing the primary color in your AppTheme and rebuild you project

Comment: add this line in your Toolbar `android:background="#66000000"`..might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed adding `android:background` attribute to the **toolbar**.

If you want to make the toolbar transparent then you can try adding:

```
android:background="@null"
```

or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

And if you want to set some specific background then:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_background_file"
```

It should solve your problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes you are right i want it transparent and tried everything like you said but still the toolbar is white the same is case with action bar if i'm trying to set action bar as transparent by default it's loading with white

Comment: @Mr.patel why not replace the toolbar with a Relative layout and give it a transparent background (or whatever background you wish)  and center the text and align the filter to the end ? I think its easier for you that way

Comment: That can be done too but i want that effect in toolbar

Comment: I have copied your code even the style.xml and the toolbar is transparent in my case. There seem to be something else that is overriding it. Check your styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

This probably because your styles contains some unwanted value in your style name. Please check your `values-21`. In my case, status bar always transparent because of the following style in `values-21` (which is generated when creating a project in Android Studio):

```
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Unwanted attribute in my project -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```